# log4net, logging, what is the biggest advantages

Tags: logging, log4net

How do you best take advantage of your logs and logging tools aside from the obvious that you have gigabytes of text telling you everything your app is doing. I am not currently using any logging in my private projects, only sending an email to myself whenever a unexpected exception occurs and I find this sufficient for my use and I cannot see the big advantage of using f.eks log4net over this.

My view is that logs are rarely used and gives you a big performance overhead and code clutter so I am a bit reluctant to start using it. Still my current employer insist we should use log4net in our projects and it is obviously used a lot so I need some help seeing the light

Answer (score 1):

Use a log reader like [L4nDash](http://www.l4ndash.com/) to give an instant overview of a large log file.

This [blog post](http://mitch-wheat.blogspot.com/2007/04/log4net-net-logging-tool.html) contains most of what you need to set up Log4Net.